# MeteorJS: How to stub validated method in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, stub

I am using validated methods (`mdg:validated-method`) with LoggedInMixin (`tunifight:loggedin-mixin`).

Now I have a problem with my unit tests, as they fail with `notLogged` error, because in the unit tests there is no logged user of course.
How do I have to stub that?

**method**

```
const resetEdit = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'reset',
  mixins: [LoggedInMixin],
  checkLoggedInError: { error: 'notLogged' }, // <- throws error if user is not logged in
  validate: null,

  run ({ id }) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

**unit test**

```
describe('resetEdit', () => {
  it('should reset data', (done) => {
    resetEdit.call({ id: 'IDString' })
  })
})
```

Unit tests throws `Error: [notLogged]`.

Comment: have you tried mocking Meteor.user and Meteor.userId? You could also try creating a fixture with a user prior to running the tests, then logging in with that user before running your test

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that, as I'm doing the unit tests in my CI workflow by using the `meteor test --once` command. So I think I cannot login any user...

Comment: you can, in your test you should be able to do something like
`Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, function({
resetEdit.call({id: "IDString"});
}));`

Comment: Did you try `resetEdit.call.call({ userId: Random.id() }, { id: 'IDString' })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

`validated-method` has a built-in way of providing a context and it is documented in the `README`, exactly for cases like the one in your question.

> method#_execute(context: Object, args: Object)
>
> Call this from your test code to simulate calling a method on behalf of a particular user:
>
> ([source](https://github.com/meteor/validated-method#method_executecontext-object-args-object))

```
  it('should reset data', (done) => {
      resetEdit._execute({userId: '123'}, { id: 'IDString' });
      done();
  });
```

---

### Original answer:

I believe that this can be achieved using the `DDP._CurrentMethodInvocation` meteor environment variable.

If you run the test in a scope where the its value is an object a `userId` string, it will be merged with the rest of the method invocation context object and the mixin will not fail.

```
describe('resetEdit', () => {
  it('should reset data', (done) => {
    DDP._CurrentMethodInvocation.withValue({userId: '123'}, function() {
      console.log(DDP._CurrentInvocation.get()); // {userId: '123'}
      resetEdit.call({ id: 'IDString' });
      done();
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: So you would recommend to not use that mixin, but to test for logged user manually in the run function?

Comment: The mixin is fine. I am not sure why `run` cannot be used directly, but I indeed found an easier way to achieve running with a synthetic context. I will update my answer to include it.